# how to push and pull blocks (rectangles) in processing game

Tags: processing, collision-detection, collision

I want my 'player' (black rectangle) to be able to push and pull on the blocks I put in my game after hitting a key (ENTER), I just have no clue on where to begin with this.

```
void keyPressed() {
int newX = x;
int newY = y;
make sure player can't move outside playing field 
if (keyCode == LEFT || keyCode == RIGHT || keyCode == UP || keyCode == DOWN) {
if (gameStaat == 2) {
  if (keyCode == LEFT && x > 40) {
    newX -= spelerStapGrootte; 
  } else if (keyCode == RIGHT && x < 440) {
    newX += spelerStapGrootte;
  } else if (keyCode == UP && y > 40) {
    newY -= spelerStapGrootte;
  } else if (keyCode == DOWN && y < 440) {
    newY += spelerStapGrootte;
  }
    if (newX != x || newY != y) {
    x = newX;
    y = newY;
    score1--;
    score2--;


//code for my player, which is just a simple rectangle
void player(int x, int y, int zijde, int color){
fill(color);
rect(x, y, zijde, zijde);
}
```

//the field where my player moves in is just a big rectangle, I hardcoded coloured blocks at random             // spots just to test the pushing pulling method

```
void drawPlayingField(int x, int y, int breedte, int hoogte) {
noFill();
strokeWeight(3);
rect(x, y, breedte, hoogte);
}
```

I am not looking for the answer, more for a general direction where to look :)
There's not many tutorials for this programming language but it is (one of) my first one.

Answer (score 1):

I presume that you are trying to move your player by using the arrow keys.  This basic demo may serve as a starting point:

```
int x, y;

void setup() {
  size(400, 400);
}

void draw() {
  background(209);
  rect(x, y, 50, 50);
}

void keyPressed() {
  if (key == CODED) {
    if (keyCode == LEFT) {
      x-=5;
    }
    if (keyCode == RIGHT) {
      x+=5;
    }
    if (keyCode == UP) {
      y-=5;
    }
    if (keyCode == DOWN) {
      y+=5;
    }
  }
}
```